# ERROR: Correlation ID: a4afb89c-b067-203a-c3a7-a8ab06a0b413

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, error

On the SharePoint site, we were seeing error in navigation in the quick launch. If we try to go to the navigation link in the site collection that failed as well. The error that showed up was:

> An error occurred while rendering  navigation for requested  URL:
>   /sites//. Exception message: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. Stack trace: at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.publishing.publishingpage.geteffectivepagecacheprofileid.

Now we can't even login to the site it just gives us the correlation ID in the title above.

Comment: Did you check the complete error in 14 hive logs?

Comment: I am using sp 2013

Comment: sp 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Use ULS Viewer to view the error details, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020

Comment: Not sure I understand all the downvotes. Are beginner level questions not welcome here?

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable the OUtput Cache on the Site? Also could you please Confirm that [Object Cache Configured for the web app properly.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx)

If Object Cache Configure then try below resolution.

**Disabled and re-enabled Publishing feature and Navigation feature for    all sites using the powershell script  which would loop through all    subsites:**

```
Get-SPWeb -site http://server.com/sites/channel -limit ALL | ForEach-Object {Disable-SPFeature Publishing -Url $_.Url -confirm:$false}

Get-SPWeb -site http://server.com/sites/channel -limit ALL | ForEach-Object {Disable-SPFeature PublishingWeb -Url $_.Url -confirm: $false}
```

**IISreset**

```
Get-SPWeb -site http://server.com/sites/channel -limit ALL | ForEach-Object {Enable-SPFeature Publishing -Url $_.Url -confirm:$false}

Get-SPWeb -site http://server.com/sites/channel -limit ALL | ForEach-Object {Enable-SPFeature PublishingWeb -Url $_.Url -confirm: $false}
```

**Unchecked following options in the site collection output cache settings:**

- Publishing sites can use a different page output cache profile
- Page layouts can use a different page output cache profile

http://praveenix.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/sharepoint-2013-left-navigation-and-top-navigation-bar-does-not-render-links-and-shows-error-an-error-occurred-while-rendering-navigation-for-requested-url/

Answer (score 1):

Please go to **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS** if you are using sharepoint 2010 or if sharepoint 2013 then **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS**.

Below the message where you are getting correlation Id you will get a time stamp. search for the logfile which is modified at this time stamp. 
Download ULS log viewer from http://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/
and open your log file in this and filter your content using correlation ID.

Answer (score 1):

The correlation id is only a reference to find log messages that are related to this issue in your log. In Central Administration you can check where your log is stored.
For SharePoint 2013 (and 2010 iirc): Central admin > Monitoring > Configure diagnostic logging

You can open the files with a simple text editor, but you might want to use a tool called ULS viewer: [ULS Viewer (by Microsoft)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020)

You can find log messages containing this correlation id. If you share your findings we might be able to help further.

ps: This is not the answer to your question, but will help us help you. Unfortunately I can't comment yet.